# Usage of Azure Compute VM Infrastructure for deploying SSIS , SSRS and SSAS services

Tags: azure, reporting-services, ssis, ssas

**My Application Architecture**

I already have a working SQL Server integrating , Analyzing and reporting applications deployed on my on-premise server. Now I am planning to deploy the same reporting application into Azure cloud. I am planning to move this application to cloud.

**My Exploration**

When I am exploring I found the data factory for data integration and transform services and later can publish to any BI tools. I was reading the data factory documentations from the following link,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction

From here I understood that I can use Azure data factory and I can perform data integration and transforming using Connect And collect stage , Transform Enrich and publish stages. And Also we can use BI tools after publishing this.

Related with moving from on-premise to Azure Cloud, I had felt some confusions. I am adding below

**My Confusion**

Without using  Azure's Data factory service , Is possible deploy my all service packages (SSIS/SSRS/SSAS) in my own Azure VM infrastructure  like what I did in on-premise machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Without using Azure's Data factory service, Is possible deploy my all
>   service packages (SSIS/SSRS/SSAS) in my own Azure VM infrastructure
>   like what I did in on-premise machine ?

Yes, you can install all the service packages in your Azure VM when you create the VM. See this description:

> Azure virtual machines allow you to deploy a wide range of computing
>   solutions in an agile way. You can deploy virtually any workload and
>   any language on nearly any operating system - Windows, Linux, or a
>   custom created one from any one of the growing list of partners.

You can just treat the virtual machine in Azure as your machine on-premise. The difference is you cannot care about the hardware and Azure will maintain it for you. You can also control the permission of your [VM with the Azure Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview). See more details about the [Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/).